# How to wrap pool.query function for error handling in node/mysql2 using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, mysql2

I'm currently rewriting a modularized node application to use async/await, inlcuding the database connection. I am using https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2 and also installed https://github.com/types/mysql2.

I want to write a wrapper function that takes the SQL statement and additional data, and returns either **(1)** a result set (for `SELECT`), **(2)** some kind of success message (for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`...) or **(3)** an error message (duplicate entry, no connection ...).

My approach so far:

*database.wrapper.ts*

```js
const pool = createPool(config.db).promise();

const query = async (sql, data, DEBUG_INFO) => {
    data = escapeSql(data);
    try {
        const [result] = await pool.query(sql, data);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        const errorMessage = logDbErrors(e, DEBUG_INFO);
        return {
            message: errorMessage,
        } as ApiResponse;
    }
};

export { query };
```

*log-db-errors.ts* (logging works as it should be)

```js
export const logDbErrors = (err: MysqlError, DEBUG_INFO = { }): string => {

    DEBUG_INFO = {
        logtype: LogTypes.MySQL,    // Set LogType to MySQL to apply proper format
        err,    // Add the MysqlError for the log files
        ...DEBUG_INFO,  // Append additionally provided information (like filename)
    };

    let message = '';

    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            message = 'Database connection was closed';
        } else if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            message = 'Database has too many connections';
        } else if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            message = 'Database connection was refused';
        } else {
            message = `Database error: ${ err.message }`;
        }
    }

    logger.error(message, DEBUG_INFO);
    return message;
};
```

You can ignore the DEBUG_INFO stuff. My problem is to return the proper type in the query function. In my services, I want to be able to query something from the database and return either multiple rows, a success info or an error:

*foo.service.ts* (as example)

```js
const createUser = async (firstName, lastName) => {
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
    const sqlData = { id: null, first_name: firstName, last_name: lastName };
    const result = await query(sql, sqlData, DEBUG_INFO);
    // return either resultset, success info or error
};
```

In this example though I'm not able to distinguish this when calling `query(...)`. I know there are RowDataPacket, OkPacket and QueryError interfaces in types/mysql2, but I cannot tell which result I get in my service.

Any tips for handling this situation? Do I need multiple functions (`querySelect()`, `queryInsert()` ...) for this? How can I return an api response using the `result` in *foo.service.ts*?

EDIT: Also came across this 'sure thing', a wrapper for promises where you define if it's okay or not (in my case result set, success or error): https://medium.com/@jesterxl/easier-error-handling-using-async-await-b9ab0cb938e#ac60
Would this be the only workaround to my problem?

Comment: you can use X11 connection and screen-saver X extension command, here an example: https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/174cff9a9cdfff527ff03f799fd1e07c017190b0/examples/smoketest/sstest.js

Comment: Hey Andrey, thanks for your answer! In the meantime I implemented interfaces (`DatabaseRequest` & `DatabaseResponse`) to pass to a function which executes the queries accordingly, which by now is working fine. I will have a look into X11 connection.